# Is it possible to tell if an override new tab page was opened because of an app install?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

The default new tab page 'bounces' the newly installed app; is there a way to do this with a new tab override page? I know I can just save a list of apps in `localStorage` or `chrome.storage` and compare the saved list with the currently installed apps, but it seems like a messy workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Till date there is no standard way of figuring out.

There is an enhancement request to include individual permissions for **`chrome_url_overrides`** instead of ***`pageToOverride`*** section, so [**chrome.management.getAll()**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#method-getAll) will identify who has overridden new_tab_page.